# Rebasing branch that was created from a feature branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I was working on a feature branch that I pushed to origin. Then I created another feature branch but I didn't checkout master before creating it. Now my second feature branch has the commits from the first feature branch which aren't yet merged to master.

I tried to rebase it and update the rebase to origin - unsuccesfully:

```
git checkout second-feature-branch
git rebase master
git push origin second-feature-branch --force
```

I already committed to the second branch.

What I have:

```
A -- B -- master
                \ 
                 \
                  first feature branch
                                      \
                                       second feature branch
```

What I want

```
                  second feature branch
                 /
                /
A -- B -- master 
                \ 
                 \
                  first feature branch
```

How do I keep only the newest commit on the new feature branch and rebase it to master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What has happened is you created the second feature branch from the first feature branch. So the second feature branch used the first feature branch as a base.

To fix it, you can create a new branch after checkout to master and then cherry-pick the commits of the second feature branch into the new branch. Then you will get the branches as you need it